# jenkins android can't find sdkmanager.jar

Tags: android, ant, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins on Mac OS. I have an ant build file that tries to execute `<exec executable="android">` in one of the targets. I have the correct path as I've included android sdk `tools` and `platform-tools` folders to it, but I am still getting the following error.

```
android can't find sdkmanager.jar
```

If I move described jar from lib folder to `tools` folder I'm getting some other similar error related to another jar, so it seems it just can't get this jar from lib folder. Please help.

Comment: Do you have sdk.dir property defined?

Comment: When I'm trying to run script from terminal everything is OK, I'm receiving this issue only when running with Jenkins.

Comment: Which script? Do you mean ant?

Comment: yeah, when I run my ant script from terminal everything is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem. I had correct path and sdk installation directory. Problem was that my Jenkins was running under another user and couldn't locate directory with android lib because they where denied for it. So problem was in sdk folder permissions.
I've just ran `chmod -R 0755 mySdkDirLocation` from console under bash and became the happiest developer on earth for the moment:)

Comment: hope it will be useful for someone experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with ANT, but this did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After I ran `chmod -R 0755 mySdkDirLocation`. The error "android can't find sdkmanager.jar" went away. But when I ran `android update sdk -u`, I cannot install archives. So I ran `chmod 777 mySdkDirLocation`. Then the downloading worked.